# divide operation in hive tables

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

I'm a beginner in hive and had some basic questions trying to manipulate a table.

I have a hive table as

```
bought  sold    fruit   
5       0       apple
0       0       mango
3       2       orange
```

I want the output as

```
agg     fruit   
0       apple
0       mango
1.5     orange
```

I'm writing an aggregate query as

```
SELECT sold/bought as agg, fruit from table GROUP BY fruit
```

I'm having two issues

1. I want the solution to be proper ex `3/2` is giving me 1 it should give 1.5
2. If bought or sold is 0, instead of Null or NaN it should give the value 0.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm.  I thought that Hive divided integers as floats.  If not, a simple solution is to multiply by 1.0:

```
SELECT sold * 1.0 / bought as agg, fruit
FROM table
GROUP BY fruit
```

Comment: But we are multiplying 0 with 1. It won't make a difference right?

Comment: @JohnConstantine . . . A difference to what?  And the multiplication factor here is `1.0` rather than `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen erratic behaviours in hive or impala. To be on safe side i would use,
`SELECT cast(sold as decimal(5,1)) / cast(bought as decimal(5,1)) as agg, fruit FROM table GROUP BY fruit`
If you want to insert data into a decimal(5,1) column, cast result as decimal(5,1). i know this is stupid but i want to be safe and avoid unnecessary version specific automatic-casting issues. I have seen calculation producing null result in one version and works just fine in other.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression where you apply your conditions:

```
select 
  case 
    when bought = 0 or sold = 0 then 0
    else 1.0 * bought / sold
  end agg,
  fruit
from tablename
```

Since you are not doing any aggregation there is no need for `GROUP BY`.